# Return error if country is not US

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have user input passing to the address key in the following query string to google maps api call:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=90002
```

In the results object that is returned, there is the address_components object which holds information about the location. I want to check the short_name and if it does not equal to US then return false and prevent the search and show a modal that says "Your country or area is not supported.".

```
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
```

Right now I am looping through the arrays and checking the short_name. It works, but is there a way to have Google provide a response if the country is not equal to the US without having to loop through? It seems like this would be a slight performance hit.

Comment: No, that functionality is not supported by the geocoder.

Comment: Got it. I will keep digging for a better approach then. Thanks!